# How to get public details from a website where I had registered using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, database, image, profile, user-profile

Is it possible to get user id (name) and profile picture from a website where I had registered.
For example, if I had registered in stackoverflow, can I get my user id and profile picture in the body using JavaScript.
I saw a user of sololearn (a coding app) used this trick to get the profile picture.

```
<img src="https://api.sololearn.com/Uploads/Avatars/"+slID+".jpg">
```

I wrote it in HTML, but he used Javascript to get user input as his sololearn profile link(numerical id) and show his profile picture.
Is it possible to get his/her user id (name) from the link also? And is it possible in other websites ?